# Can't access context resources with embebbed Jetty

Tags: java, servlets, embedded-jetty

I have embebbed Jetty web app, it's built similar to this example: https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-live-war

I'm trying to access resource file with `SerletContext`:

```java
ServletContext ctx = ...;
InputStream stream = ctx.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/classes/jdbc.properties");
```

but I'm getting `null` instead of input-stream.
I've checked that this file can be accessed in final war archive:

```sh
$ cd ./livewar-assembly/target/
$ unzip livewar-assembly-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war 
$ find . -type f -name jdbc.properties
./WEB-INF/classes/jdbc.properties
```

I'm creating the server with this code:

```java
final Server server = new Server(port);
final WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
final Configuration.ClassList classes = Configuration.ClassList
    .setServerDefault(server);
classes.addBefore(
    "org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration",
    "org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration"
);
webapp.setContextPath("/");
webapp.setWar(WAR.toString());
server.setHandler(webapp);
```

Why I can't access resource file and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried to just access `jdbc.properties`?  The `WEB-INF/classes` should be implied.

Comment: @stdunbar yes, I tried `ctx.getResourceAsStream("jdbc.properties")` but same result

Comment: Sorry - I should have asked about `/jdbc.properties` - notice the leading `/`.

Comment: @stdunbar just tried `/jdbc.properties` - getting `null` stream

Comment: The problem is your `WAR.toString()` that has to be accurate for the various ServletContext methods to function properly.   The embedded-jetty-live-war example has 2 different mode DEV/PROD for that value, be sure you understand that this value MUST be a fully qualified URI, never a relative path.